# InitWithDictionary causes original NSMutableDictionary to be changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I originally have a single NSMutableDictionary. Then I initialize another NSMutableDictionary by using:

```
self.originalDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.newDict];
```

Both have NSStrings as keys and NSMutableArray as values.

When I later do:
...

```
 NSArray *keys = [self.newDict allKeys];
    for(NSString *key in keys){
        [[self.newDict objectForKey:key] filterUsingPredicate:[self predicateForSearchString:searchString]];
        */
    }
```

This caused my original dictionary to be changed as well. What am I doing wrong? Is it maybe another reason?

Comment: try method initWithDictionary:copyItems:

Comment: when I add copyItems I get termination: "-[__NSArrayI filterUsingPredicate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: both NSMutableDictionary are declared (nonatomic, strong) btw

Comment: try to use _newDict instead of self.newDict. probably you have the methods setNewDict where you override the originalDict everytime. I just tried and it works ok for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.originalDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.theDict copyItems:YES];
```

Comment: when I add copyItems I get termination: "-[__NSArrayI filterUsingPredicate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" for some reason

Comment: which means [self.newDict objectForKey:key] is now an NSArray instead of NSMutableArray, what's the content of [self.newDict objectForKey:key]? try log it out.

Comment: You can use filteredArrayUsingPredicate on NSArray, thus error will go away

Comment: Yeah, when I log it out I see that it is an NSArray. However, I want to update that particular entry with the new filteredArray. When using [[self.newDict objectForKey:key] setObject:filteredArray forKey:key] I get: "NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance "

Comment: use  [self.newDict setObject:currentArray forKey:key]

Comment: Ahh, of course. Blinded of my own mistakes after some hours of coding. Thanks!